Flutter : How to create this scrollable widget in flutter?

I'm trying to create a design like the image shown using flutter, the middle part where it can be scrolled left and right and set the price for the sneaker.
Does anyone know how to achieve this ? I have try to use slider but is not the design I want.

Do you mean the scrollable "dots" ?? I dont know if there is any package for it, but you can create something like this using ListView and global keys.
Just create horizontal ListView, where one item is Column of "dots" and asign a key to this item. Use a listener for ListView ScrollController and check for the middle item with the help of the global keys.
You can find out how to get widget position here: Get "y" position of container on Flutter
You get item position and size and compare it to the middle of the screen(or better, to the middle of the ListView - you can also assign a key to a ListView and calculate middle from its size).
Once you have index of the middle item, just perform some changes (change padding etc.) for middle item and items next to it.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
